# How to Pipe shell command into a file and read its contents using python?

Tags: python, pipe, popen

I need to execute a command, save its output into a file and then read the contents of the file. This is what I have so far:

```
file_out = open('if','w')
ls = sp.Popen(["ls","-1","/sys/class/net"],stdout=file_out)
file_out.close()
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('if')]
print(lines)
```

The file is indeed created with the desired contents. But when I execute the script it outputs only a `[]`

Answer (score 3):

the reason is the subprocess `ls` don't terminate immediately. and the output has not yet been written to file. you can add `ls.wait()` before read file to ensure the previous subprocess already terminate

if you don't want to communicate with subprocess, but only to execute it, you can use `retcode = sp.call(["ls","-1","/sys/class/net"],stdout=file_out)`. this way, the subprocess is ensured terminated and has return code.

if you only need output but the file, you can use pipe, and don't need to save output in file. the code is below:

```
ls = sp.Popen(["ls","-1","/sys/class/net"],stdout=sp.PIPE)
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in ls.stdout]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sergio:  `lines = sp.check_output(["ls","-1","/sys/class/net"], universal_newlines=True).splitlines()`